# using python class methods inside java

Tags: java, python

I have three different classes written in python. They contain several methods which I want to use them inside my java program (creating objects from these python classes and use these objects to call the methods). Actually my level in java might be intermediate. However, i am absolutely new in python. I have read that it is possible to use Python class methods inside java but there is no clear way that is well explained. So, please help me with a script or a tutorial or any advice that can help understanding using python classes methods in java.

Comment: I would say rewrite the classes in Java. I don't think you need to go through all that hassle just for three classes (well, of course it depends on their sizes).

Comment: Although I might be in the wrong, I believe Jython can be used to achieve this functionality.  http://www.jython.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jython is the way to go. If you have a couple of hours I would recommend you go over the [tutorial](http://wiki.python.org/jython/LearningJython) for it.

If you are curious to see how jython can be used inside java skip to:
http://wiki.python.org/jython/LearningJython#integrating-jython-python-into-java